# Softaculous/AMPPS - The installation package could not be found (localhost)

Tags: installation, xampp, localhost, wamp, softaculous

`The installation package could not be found` error returns after I hit install on `http://localhost/ampps/` for most of the available packages such as Wikimedia.

I tried to find out where this error comes from such as updating setting in

```
http://localhost/ampps-admin/
```

and no success yet. Anyone with any recommendation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the folder `Ampps/ampps/scripts/mw` and try installing again from `http://localhost/ampps` again.

Softaculous will download the package automatically if not found.